# How to iterate over a hash that contains deep nested array using helper method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash with a deep nested array. I need to iterate over it and find the value of `56H`, for example, and pull its related human readable name `Manager`. Using a helper method in rails, how can I do that? Here is the hash table:

```
HASH_TABLE = {
        'Users' => [['Manger','56H'],
                    ['Admin', '56A'],
                    ['Policy', '56B'],
                    ['Member','78C'],
                    ['Guest','764']],
      'Visitor' => [['Worker','55H'],
                    ['Employee','55A'],
                    ['Guest','55B'],
                    ['Temp Member','78C'],
                    ['NA','764AA']]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "Human readable name"

Comment: @AaditiJain I've updated the question to clarify based upon a comment that Nicholas provided on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had more than one address to look up, you might do this:

```
HASH_TABLE.each_with_object({}) { |(_,v),h|
  v.each { |type, value| h[value] = type } }
  #=> {"56H"=>"Manager",     "56A"=>"Admin", "56B"=>"Policy",
  #    "78C"=>"Temp Member", "764"=>"Guest", "55H"=>"Worker",
  #    "55A"=>"Employee",    "55B"=>"Guest", "764AA"=>"NA"}

h["56H"] #=> "Manager"
h["55B"] #=> "Guest"
```

Two other ways of constructing the hash:

```
h = Hash[HASH_TABLE.values.flatten(1).map(&:reverse)]
```

and

```
h = Hash[HASH_TABLE.values.flatten(1)].invert
```

If the same "key" (e.g., `"Employee"`) were in both `HASH_TABLE['Users']` and `HASH_TABLE['Visitor']`, this might be more useful:

```
h = HASH_TABLE.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  v.each { |type, value| h[value] = [k, type] } }
  # => {"56H"  =>["Users", "Manager"],    "56A"=>["Users", "Admin"],
  #     "56B"  =>["Users", "Policy"],     "78C"=>["Visitor", "Temp Member"],
  #     "764"  =>["Users", "Guest"],      "55H"=>["Visitor", "Worker"],
  #     "55A"  =>["Visitor", "Employee"], "55B"=>["Visitor", "Guest"],
  #     "764AA"=>["Visitor", "NA"]}

h["56H"] #=> ["Users",   "Manager"]
h["55B"] #=> ["Visitor", "Guest"]
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks Cary. So flatten(1) removes the top level array. What's reverse?

Comment: `['Manger','56H'].reverse #=> ['56H', 'Manger']`, in preparation for creating the hash containing `'56H'=>"Manager"`.

Comment: Interesting. What I thought is that it actually returned a new hash, not realizing that it was a hash in the first place, i.e. Hash[]. Am I right?

Comment: The part inside `Hash[]` is an array `arr`. The class method [Hash::[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) converts `arr` to a hash. In Ruby 2.0 you can instead write `arr.to_h`.

Comment: This is the best answer, IMHO. Hash tables are designed to deliver the value given the key. OP's hash is kinda useless as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding the structure or the context, my best answer is to iterate over each element in the hash, then each array in the hash value.  I'm not sure here what you mean by "human readable name" since both the hash keys & the first array element is a human readable name.  I assumed you meant the hash key in my code below, but this might not be correct.

```
def human_readable_name(str)
  HASH_TABLE.each do |key, array|
    array.each do |entry|
      return entry[0] if entry[1] == str
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. What I mean by 'human readable name' is the name of a code associated in the array, i.e. "56H" will have 'Manger' readable name. Literally, I need to pass a code to a method and pull it's related value, i.e. 'human readable name'. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Thanks @NicholasAlek, I've updated the answer to satisfy that need.

Comment: Yep, that worked just fine. How do I pull a key, i.e "Users" and set it in a helper as well?

Comment: Nicholas, please edit your question instead of appending your queries here.That way its clear what you exactly want and easier for anyone to answer :). Have an upvote @MattHuggins for the sheer quickness! :D

Comment: @NicholasAlek you would just need to `return key` instead of `return entry[0]` if you want the "Users" string.